Named Pipe security problem on some Windows clients
I'm using named pipe for a communication inside a C# process. The software is used on different Windows PCs. On some PCs my software is working and on some I get the following error:
"Some or all identity references could not be translated."
I can't find any log entry in the Windows Event Log nor in the Windows Firewall log.
Thats the code I'm using:
PipeSecurity pipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("Users", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite | PipeAccessRights.CreateNewInstance, AccessControlType.Allow));


The error "Some or all identity references could not be translated." means that one those machines your group name "Users" did not exist. These groups might have a different name on different machines, e.g. on machines with a non-english OS language.
Try using security identifiers (sid) instead:
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);
var usersAccount = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
pipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(usersAccount, ...


The Users group was missing. Using an English system everything is fine. Using a non English system we have the error.

Seems you could pass the sid object directly, as its base class is IdentityReference
